# How do I query the same node where data was inserted?

Tags: cassandra

how do I get that the same node where  is inserted is the same node of query.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Short question - if you mean, how do you ensure that your query chooses a co-ordinator which is also holding a replica of the data, use one of the token-aware policies, and that will happen by default.

If you are worried that you will connect and query a node which does not have the data - no need to worry, it will act as the co-ordinator and retrieve the data from as many nodes as it needs to satisfy the consistency level of the request.

Answer (score 1):

In Cassandra, a node which owns a partition is called a replica. Replicas are where copies of the data are stored.

As a general rule, the default load-balancing policy used by the Cassandra drivers are token-aware meaning that the driver favours picking a replica of the partition as coordinator for the request where possible.

Note that the coordinator for the request is not guaranteed to be the replica, but the driver has preference for replicas over other nodes in the cluster when it generates the query plan (a list of hosts the driver contacts to coordinate requests).

For details on how it works, I recommend having a look at the [Load balancing section of the Java driver docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/load_balancing/). Cheers!